# Is there a function in javascript similar to compact from php?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, variables

I found `compact` function very useful (in php). Here is what it does:

```
$some_var = 'value';
$ar = compact('some_var');
//now $ar is array('some_var' => 'value')
```

So it create array from variables which you specify, when key for elements is variable name.
Is there any kind of function in javascript ?

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45884534/6047611

Comment: Done. But it seems unusual on stackoverflow to change accepted answer after 4 years.

Comment: Thank you, this will help the next person who finds this post 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use ES6/ES2015 [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

*Example:*

```
let bar = 'bar', foo = 'foo', baz = 'baz'; // declare variables

let obj = {bar, foo, baz}; // use object initializer

console.log(obj);

{bar: 'bar', foo: 'foo', baz: 'baz'} // output
```

Beware of browsers compatibilities, you always can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Answer (score 4):

No there is no analogous function nor is there any way to get variable names/values for the current context -- only if they are "global" variables on `window`, which is not recommended.  If they are, you could do this:

```
function compact() {
    var obj = {};
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function (elem) {
        obj[elem] = window[elem];
    });
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: this seems dangerous and undesirable, i'd not recommend this approach. a much better solution is > https://stackoverflow.com/a/45884534/1757364

Comment: @Gavin agreed, this answer is 5 years old. Object initialization shorthand is now commonly available and is a much better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [phpjs library](http://phpjs.org/functions/compact/) for using the same function in javascript same as in php

### Example

```
var1 = 'Kevin'; var2 = 'van'; var3 = 'Zonneveld';
compact('var1', 'var2', 'var3');
```

### Output

```
{'var1': 'Kevin', 'var2': 'van', 'var3': 'Zonneveld'}
```

Comment: Thanks i forgot about recursive compacting

Answer (score 0):

If the variables are not in global scope it is still kinda possible but not practical.

```
function somefunc() {
    var a = 'aaa',
        b = 'bbb';

    var compact = function() {
        var obj = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var key = arguments[i];
            var value = eval(key);
            obj[key] = value;
        }
        return obj;
    }
    console.log(compact('a', 'b')) // {a:'aaa',b:'bbb'}
}
```

The good news is ES6 has a new feature that will do just this.

```
var a=1,b=2;
console.log({a,b}) // {a:1,b:2}
```