# JavaScript equivalent of PHP's compact() method?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

In PHP you can do this:

```
$hello = "world";
$goodbye = "everyone";
$whatever = "taco";
$something = 5;
$hey = false;
$myArray = compact('hello','goodbye','whatever','something','hey');
```

And now you have the following array:

```
[
  'hello' => 'world',
  'goodbye' => 'everyone',
  'whatever' => 'taco',
  'something' => 5,
  'hey' => false
]
```

Is there anything like this in vanilla JavaScript or NodeJS libraries?

Comment: are you looking for [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir I would doubt the OP is.

Comment: How about having a look at this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270749/is-there-a-function-in-javascript-similar-to-compact-from-php

Answer (score 1):

[The PHP.js project](http://phpjs.org) is dedicated to the very task of porting all of PHP's native functions to JavaScript.

The compact function is available [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/compact/), and I'll also copy it below.

```
function compact() {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/compact/
  // original by: Waldo Malqui Silva (http://waldo.malqui.info)
  // improved by: Jack
  //    input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  //   example 1: var1 = 'Kevin'; var2 = 'van'; var3 = 'Zonneveld';
  //   example 1: compact('var1', 'var2', 'var3');
  //   returns 1: {'var1': 'Kevin', 'var2': 'van', 'var3': 'Zonneveld'}

  var matrix = {},
    that = this;

  var process = function(value) {
    var i = 0,
      l = value.length,
      key_value = '';
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      key_value = value[i];
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(key_value) === '[object Array]') {
        process(key_value);
      } else {
        if (typeof that.window[key_value] !== 'undefined') {
          matrix[key_value] = that.window[key_value];
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  };

  process(arguments);
  return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can't read from the current symbol table like that using a user defined function.

You would need to construct it another way, like using an object.

```
var obj = {
  'hello': 'world'
};
```

The other alternatives was to look them up if they were global using the global object (`window` in a browser) or use `eval()`, which shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box? No. However, you can take advantage of something like [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

If your variables are all attached to the global `window` object, then you could do something like this:

```
function compact() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  return args.reduce(function(t, c) {
    if(c in window) t[c] = window[c];

    return t;
  }, {});
}
```

## Output bound to `window`:

[image: output]

This will just take advantage of the fact that in browser environments, global variables are scoped to the `window` object. What if you don't have a `window` object? Do this:

```
function compact() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  return args.reduce(function(t, c) {
    if(c in this) t[c] = this[c];

    return t;
  }.bind(this), {});
}

compact('some', 'global', 'variables');
```

This has to happen at the **top level** though (i.e., wherever your global context is).

## Output bound to `this`:

[image: output2]